# Adding an extra line to a text file after every N lines

Tags: unix, awk

Hi I have a Unix command that produces a list of ip addresses along with  other columns information . i want to add something to the command so that it displays it as a set of 3 lines then a space or ---- and then the next 3 lines and so on.

how can I achieve this ?

for example:

```
1.2.3.4    xy
1.3.5.7    ab
1.25.7.9   cd
-------------
1.25.7.8   kl
1.3.4.5    mn
1.25.7.8   op
-------------
1.24.5.6   la
1.3.4.5    ka
1.25.7.8   xz
```

Comment: That is your desired output? What does the input look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `awk` to print an extra line after every 40 lines:

```
awk '{ print $0; if(++i % 40 == 0) printf("-------------\n") }' file
```

Change `% 40` to `% 3` to print that extra line after every 3 lines.

Comment: Why mod 40? Wouldn't that be mod 4?

Comment: The title says `set of 40`.

Comment: Or, more simply: `awk '1; NR%3==0 {print "----"}' file`

Comment: hi Thanks a lot awk '{ print $0; if(++i % 40 == 0) printf("-------------\n") }' file worked perfectly. i would like to understand the usage of print $0 here.I tried print $1 instead to play around and it printed just the first column but $0 prints all 4.

Comment: `$0` represents the entire line and `$1` etc., represent the individual fields.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Sorry for the trouble , but could you please kindly  advise documentation for the use of `'1;` in awk? I can not find anything about this strange awk syntax that tickles my mind these  days.

Comment: `1` is the conventional arbitrary non-zero value to indicate true.   Writing `1` as a pattern on its own with no action is basically equivalent to writing the action `{print}`

Comment: @EdMorton Thank you Ed for the suggestion. I recently got this book, is quite usefull. I just could not locate this `1` thing, but i have not read the whole book carefully yet.

Comment: That's what I mean about understanding the paradigm. awk scripts are `condition { action }` blocks with the default condition being `true` and the default action `print $0`. So `{print $0}` = `true_condition {print $0}` and also `true_condition` = `true_condition {print $0}`. Now - guess what `1` is. Just like in `C` and other algol-based languages, when used in the context of a condition any non-zero number means `true` and zero means `false`. So `1` = `true` = `true{print $0}` = `{print $0}` = `{print}` (that last because the default for what gets printed is $0).

Comment: @codeforester think about the difference in values between your variable `i` and the builtin variable `NR`. If there is no difference then what's the point of `i`? Also why do `printf "---\n"` instead of the more simple and more robust wrt ORS setting `print "---"` (`printf` is a builtin btw not a function so `printf("foo")` isn't harmful AFAK but it doesn't do what you think it does as the parens are grouping an expression, not function argument delimiters). Finally - that won't produce the posted expected output since it'll add a `---` line at the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ seq 9 | awk 'NR>1 && (NR%3)==1{print "---"} 1'
1
2
3
---
4
5
6
---
7
8
9
```